Sorting orders of layers for presentation
This is basic functionality that I use often but cannot get it to work on a particular project. QGIS 3.16.
I have three symbology rules on a layer. The 'sub' layer(rule) that should be on top keeps getting presented on the bottom(pink). I have deleted it and recreated the rule but no use. Have tried re-ordering the layers/rules many times but no use. I have looked for hidden parameters that may have been ticked - but none.
The pink layer should be on top. I see from a previous question in 2019 that someone else had the same problem but dont see a conclusive answer.
Can you help?


I'm expecting yellow at the bottom - all good, Red as the middle layer - all good, then pink on top but it looks like it's been shoved to the bottom.


Please first check if it really is placed at the bottom, or if it only looks like that - by turning off the other rules in the layer window.

What are your rules? If you are using Categorized symbology, you need to use the 'Control feature rendering order' option. The order in the legend, or the order of the rules, is not the rendering order

Erik - Yes I have turned on and off other rules, even tried deleting the problem rule and recreated it - but still the punk layer gets presented at the bottom.

Andre - I am using rule base symbology. Never had a problem doing this before.

The order of the rules/legend definitely does not dictate the order in which the features are painted on the map. Go to 'Control feature rendering order' and use expression to_date('DT', 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en') (like in your symbol rules). The features will then be rendered by date, and you can check if Ascending or Descending is what you want

Andre - I always thought the order in the legend defines the presentation, so thanks for this information. I could not find the 'control feature rendering order' option but I did find an option for 'Symbol Levels' This deals with the render order. I applied an assending count (1,2,3) to each layer and that seems to have worked. Thanks for the guidance.
